# SQLite passing multiple parameter in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, join, subquery

I have this query which is working in MYSQL but will not run in SQLite. I think its fails because of the multiple parameter in the WHERE clause.

The purpose is to select the only the latest survey answer (said) for all survey questions (sqid) since multiple answers to a question are possible.

```
SELECT sqid, said, saname, satimestamp
FROM surveyanswer 
WHERE (sqid, hoid, satimestamp) IN (
    SELECT sqid, hoid, max(satimestamp) as satimestamp
    FROM surveyanswer
    GROUP BY sqid
)
```

I have experimented with ordering by the satimestamp and selected a limit of one instead of max but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Even if SQLite would support the tuple comparison you still have an error in your sub-select due to the "illegal" use of the `GROUP BY`: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a join:

```
SELECT sqid, said, saname, satimestamp
FROM surveyanswer A
JOIN (
    SELECT sqid, hoid, max(satimestamp) as satimestamp
    FROM surveyanswer
    GROUP BY sqid
) B ON A.sqid = B.sqid and A.hoid = B.hoid and A.satimestamp = B.satimestamp
```

Which is functionally like your original SQL but since you only care about time I believe this will work as well:

```
SELECT sqid, said, saname, satimestamp
FROM surveyanswer A
JOIN (
    SELECT max(satimestamp) as satimestamp
    FROM surveyanswer
) B ON A.satimestamp = B.satimestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that you are using the `hoid` field for anything.  So, I removed it.  Does the following produce what you are looking for:

```
SELECT sa.sqid, sa.said, sa.saname, sa.satimestamp
FROM surveyanswer sa
WHERE sa.satimestamp IN (
    SELECT max(subsa.satimestamp)
    FROM surveyanswer subsa
    WHERE sa.sqid = subsa.sqid
)
```

If the `hoid` field needs to be included in the where clause then try the following:

```
SELECT sa.sqid, sa.said, sa.saname, sa.satimestamp
FROM surveyanswer sa
WHERE sa.satimestamp IN (
    SELECT max(subsa.satimestamp)
    FROM surveyanswer subsa
    WHERE sa.sqid = subsa.sqid
    AND sa.hoid = subsa.hoid
)
```